# Unblur Image on Hover with CSS

Tags: css

Here is my code so far:

```css
.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card .cover-image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: blur(8px);
  transition: filter 0.25s linear;
}

.card .cover-image:hover {
  filter: blur(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img class="cover-image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/rock600x400.jpg">
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img class="cover-image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg">
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img class="cover-image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/newyork.jpg">
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img class="cover-image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/sanfran.jpg">
</div>
```

However, when I hover over the images they don't unblur. I think this is because of the z-index on the cover image. Is there any workaround for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: It is, so why the need of `z-index`

Comment: @LGSon For the 50% opacity background color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try

```
.card:hover .cover-image{
  filter: blur(0);
}
```

because you are hovering over the parent of the img actually

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the z-index is causing this (try removing that line and you can see that it works). This is because the image is now 'behind' the transparent `div` that contains it, so the hover event only applies to the parent. If you need the z-index to be there, you could target the parent element for hover detection instead. Just replace `.card .cover-image:hover` with `.card:hover .cover-image`.